# Unable To Access library activity in another project

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-tabhost, android-library

I am trying to access library activity into another project(In tabhost
 and each tab call different activity.) but its throwing exception

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find
explicit activity class
{com.themontcalm.droid.activity/com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activity.ReservationTab};
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

> where :-   `com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activity.ReservationTab` is a
>   library project.    And `com.themontcalm.droid.activity` launcher
>   project where i am  accessing library activity
>
> code where i am accessing my project library:---

```
package com.themontcalm.droid.activity;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TabHost;


public class HomeScreen extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {
    TabHost tabHost;
    ImageButton location, contacts, explore;
    Intent intent;
    //LocationGB locationActivity = new LocationGB();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    //LocationFactory.getInstance().setLocationActivity(LocationGB.class);

        // addListenerOnButton(); 
        location = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.location);
        contacts = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.contacts);
        explore = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.explore);

        location.setOnClickListener(this);
        contacts.setOnClickListener(this);
        explore.setOnClickListener(this);
        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

        tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)

        intent = new Intent().setClass(getBaseContext(), com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activity.ReservationTab.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("RESERVATION")
                .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.testing))// ,
                                                                        // res.getDrawable(R.drawable.testing)
                .setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activity.GalleryTabActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("MODIFY")
                .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.testing))// ,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.testing)
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activity.VideoTabActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("VIDEO")
                .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.testing))// ,
                                                                        // res.getDrawable(R.drawable.testing)
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // set tab which one you want open first time 0 or 1 or 2
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == location) {
    //  intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, LocationGB.class);
    //      HomeScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (v == contacts) {
            intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activity.ContactInfo.class);
            HomeScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
        } else if (v == explore) {
            intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activity.ExplorePropertyActivity.class);
            HomeScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: have u made lib project property as "is library"? did u include ur lib project in ur main project??

Comment: yes and already added in launcher project

Comment: while refering that class name it must be asking for import did u do that?

Comment: yes did that and it also throwing error :- MontcalmLibs] Could not find MontcalmLibs.apk! –

Comment: do u hv source of lib project u r adding?

Comment: yes i made the project and checked as library and created new project to access that library.

Comment: i m not asking that i m asking is ur libaray project a apk?i mean it contains class files or its source is avaialbe?

Comment: check the post i have edited with the code where i am accessing that library

Comment: library project have some activity

Comment: thanks for help .... i placed all activity declaration in launcher project manifest file and its working –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I doubt that `<activity>` tag declaration in manifest file will work but
>   give a try and do include this in manifest file:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activityr"
android:required="true" />
```

Comment: declare ur activity in ur main project with its package name

Comment: i did that and its working i placed all activity declaration in launcher project manifest file and its working... i wonder why....

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activity.ReservationTab library in your current project. To do this,

1. go to properties and then Android, below there is Library part, click to add button and select your library.
2. That was it before eclipse get updated, but now you should also go Java Built Path and select your library.

Comment: i did those process... and it also throwing error :-  MontcalmLibs] Could not find MontcalmLibs.apk!

Comment: i have cleaned my launcher project and library project several times it does not helped me...

Comment: Finally, whould you mind to share the code snipped how you call that class in your launcher project?

Comment: check the post i have edited with the code where i am accessing that library

Comment: Ok, with this code intent = new Intent().setClass(getBaseContext(), com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activity.ReservationTab.class); you only declare its class, you may need to set its package as well.

Comment: Can you try to call that activity like this:
Intent intent = new Intent("com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activity.ReservationTab");
intent.setClassName("com.themontcalm.droid.activity", "com.themontcalm.droid.lib.activity.ReservationTab");

Comment: thanks for help ....  i placed all activity declaration in launcher project manifest file and its working

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are linking the library projects as a library rather than external jar. go to Project `properties > Android > Library`, then click add library.

Then as you are doing define the activity in your project manifest

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="fullpath.LibraryProjectActivity" >    
</activity>
```

Comment: may i have to define library activity in launcher project where i am accessing it

Comment: yes u have to add in the manifest file of the launcher project too