# Starting library Activity from another library project

Tags: android, android-library

I have a library(LIB2) project that depends on another library(LIB1) project that I compiled as AAR and uploaded on Archiva.

When I try to start a LIB1 Activity from LIB2 by using:

```
startActivity(new Intent(HelperActivity.this, xx.company.blabla.package.login.LoginActivity.class));
```

I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

So I did some research and I tried the solutions found here:
[Error calling Android activity from .aar library.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166606/error-calling-android-activity-from-aar-library) and here: [Using an Android library project Activity within another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157616/using-an-android-library-project-activity-within-another-project/9822278#9822278).

Now, if I do, as suggested by the solutions that I've found,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("xx.company.blabla.package.login",
            "xx.company.blabla.package.login.LoginActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="xx.company.blabla.package.login.LoginActivity"/>
```

I get error ActivityNotFoundException

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {xx.company.blabla.package.login/xx.company.blabla.package.login.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

The fact is that I indeed declared the Activity in the Manifest so I can't understand why it does not see it.

Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("xx.company.blabla.package.login",
            "xx.company.blabla.package.login.LoginActivity"));
```

Android will find package `xx.company.blabla.package.login` later set it is folder container package `xx.company.blabla.package.login`; finally find class `LoginActivity`. Try:

```
try {
    Class classLoginActivity = Class.forName("xx.company.blabla.package.login.LoginActivity");

    startActivity(new Intent(HelperActivity .this, classLoginActivity));
}catch (Exception e){

}
```

Hope it can help you!

Comment: I get NullPointerException.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xx.company.blabla/xx.company.blabla.package.login.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: Maybe you has error config library. Android can't find your library.