# Merging manifest of library is giving error in android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have simple application in which I want to use component of library project that I imported.

I merged the manifest of library and main project by adding `manifestmerger.enabled=true` in `project.properties` so that I can use components of library project into main project.

But when I tried to start activity of library project from main project with the code below:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("scanType", REGISTER_BARCODE);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I got the following errors

```
02-20 01:51:46.524: E/AndroidRuntime(23675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 01:51:46.524: E/AndroidRuntime(23675): Process: com.example.smartdna_l1, PID: 23675
02-20 01:51:46.524: E/AndroidRuntime(23675): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.smartdna_l1/com.linksmart.smartdna6.ScanActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

-

```
{com.example.smartdna_l1/com.linksmart.smartdna6.ScanActivity}
```

Where `com.example.smartdna_l1` is main project package and `com.linksmart.smartdna6.ScanActivity` is library project path.

The path which got detected is wrong.

Now my question is that how to avoid merging of path so appropriate activity path can be detected correctly to start the activity.

Comment: Did you create both the library and app projects in Android Studio? Can you provide the directory structure of these projects and the AndroidManifest.xml files for each?

Comment: No, I am working with Eclipse not android studio... @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("packagename//com.linksmart.smartdna6", 
                                     "classname//com.linksmart.smartdna6.ScanActivity"));
intent.putExtra("scanType", REGISTER_BARCODE);
startActivity(intent);
```

Make sure that in your library you've declared `ScanActivity` in library `AndroidManifest.xml`

For more info check [Using an Android library project Activity within another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157616/using-an-android-library-project-activity-within-another-project)

Hope this helps!